# Django with jquery: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, django

I have attached my jquery to my django project and I find there is **Uncaught ReferenceError error** ,though the **jquery behavior is present**

***My base html***

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            {% block jquery %}
            {% endblock %}
        });
    </script>
```

Another html page which ***extends base.html***

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load staticfiles %}

    {% block content %}

        <script>
            {% block jquery %}
                $('h3').css('color','red');
                alert('hello')        
            {% endblock %}      
        </script>

        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3 id="price">{{ object.price }}</h3>
                {% if object.variation_set.count > 1 %}
                    <select class="form-control variation_select">
                        {% for var in object.variation_set.all %}
                            <option data-price='{{ var.price }}' data-sale-price='{{ var.sale_price }}' value="{{ var.id }}">{{ var }} </option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>


    {% endblock %}
```

Though the **error** is present **jquery is working well** as the 19.95 is turned to red. What could be the issue?. I did check and found jquery is loaded

Any help is much appreciated...Thanks in adavance

[image]

Comment: try this: `// check if Jquery is available
function checkJquery() {
  if (window.jQuery) {
    // jQuery is loaded
    alert("Jquery is working!");
  } else {
    // jQuery is not loaded
    alert("Jquery does not ork");
  }
} and report back`

Comment: @luke_aus   ->  It says Jquery is working......................

Comment: hmm - I have had a similar error before - can't remember the problem though. Check that you only have one reference to the jquery source.